# Bitbucket pipeline failed while trying to use prisma:generate command

Tags: nestjs, bitbucket, prisma, bitbucket-pipelines

my bitbucket pipeline failed while trying to run `yarn prisma:generate`.
The error i got:

```
Error:  
Generating client into /my-app/node_modules/prisma/prisma-client is not allowed.
This package is used by `prisma generate` and overwriting its content is dangerous.
Suggestion:
Generate client into /my-app/node_modules/prisma/prisma-client instead
You won't need to change your imports.
Imports from `@prisma/client` will be automatically forwarded to `.prisma/client`
```

**Configuration:**

- schema.prisma:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  output   = "../node_modules/prisma/prisma-client"
}
```

- package.json:

```
"@prisma/client": "^4.1.0",
"prisma": "^4.1.0"
```

The suggestion I got is the same path I provide.

Before 2 weeks anything works well.
Does someone know what is the problem?